# How to return new non abstract Map from lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Could you guys help me how to get result as `List<Map<Long, MapDifference>` instead of `List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long, MapDifference>>`?

Input is List. Object has id, and two different List objects - left and right. I want to compare them and associate difference with id. Then return that whole list of MapDifferences with id

I have following piece of code:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long, MapDifference>> mapDifferences = input
        .stream()
        .map(h -> {
            Optional<Map<String, List<String>>> left = Optional.ofNullable(..Object1.);
            Optional<Map<String, List<String>>> right = Optional.ofNullable(..Object2..);
            MapDifference mapDifference = Maps.difference(left.orElseGet(LinkedTreeMap::new), right.orElseGet(LinkedTreeMap::new));
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long, MapDifference>((long) h.get("property"), mapDifference);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Do you mean `Map<Long, MapDifference>` not `List<Map<Long, MapDifference>>`? Because I don't fully see how returning a list of maps makes much sense in this case.

Comment: I *think* I need List<Map<Long, MapDifference>>. Input is List<Object> which has id, and two different List<String> - left and right. I want to compare them and associate difference with id. Then return that whole list of MapDifferences with id.

Comment: Why are you using raw `MapDifference`s?

Comment: Can you post the input structure?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - right, now I see, why I don't need to wrap everything into List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `Optional::ofNullable` should not be used to do a simple `null` check.

Next you can use `Collections::singletonMap` and your code look like:

```
List<Map<Long, MapDifference>> mapDifferences = input
  .stream()
  .map(h -> {
    Map<String, List<String>> left = object1 == null ? new LinkedTreeMap<>() : object1;
    Map<String, List<String>> right = object2 == null ? new LinkedTreeMap<>() : object2;
    MapDifference mapDifference = Maps.difference(left, right);
    return Collections.singletonMap((long) h.get("property"), mapDifference);
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Or if you want to flatten your structure and there are only unique `property` numbers, then use:

```
Map<Long, MapDifference> mapDifferences = input
  .stream()
  .map(h -> {
    Map<String, List<String>> left = object1 == null ? new LinkedTreeMap<>() : object1;
    Map<String, List<String>> right = object2 == null ? new LinkedTreeMap<>() : object2;
    MapDifference mapDifference = Maps.difference(left, right);
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((long) h.get("property"), mapDifference);
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: What's with the raw types?

Comment: @shmosel Fixed. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Next question would be whether `new LinkedTreeMap<>()` really is needed here or if `Collections.emptyMap()` would suffice…

Comment: @Holger I personally would also use `Collections.emptyMap()`, but I've used the already given code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need Map as Silvio mentioned. Following code returns map which keys is input id and corresponding value is a difference between this input left and right list. I skipped calculating difference.

```
class Example {
    static class Input {
        Long id;
    }

    static class MapDifference {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(new Input(), new Input())
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  input -> input.id,
                  input -> {
                      // calculate difference
                      return new MapDifference();
                  }
              ));
    }
}
```